# How to create packages at runtime?

Tags: java

I am new to java programming language.

Can you please tell me how to create a package at runtime?(I mean while compling the program).

Comment: runtime is the opposite of compile time.

Comment: Do you mean a actual java package (as in "java.lang package") or a distributable package (as in "a jar file")?

Comment: why would you create an actual java package at runtime?? do you mean a jar file?

Comment: to create a jar file: http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Answer (score 5):

I think you have misunderstood the "package" concept.

Packages is an organization of classes very similar to a directory structure, but with a convention that they should start with the authors DNS domain reversed.

You may want to read up on the Java Tutorial.  The appropriate page is http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html

Comment: very nice answer. I'm giving +1

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen It could be added that Class objects have a getPackage() method, which return an instance of java.lang.Package. This class has a private constructor, and I assume that packages can be created at runtime using reflection: **Package p = Package.class.getConstructor(String.class, Manifest.class, URL.class, ClassLoader.class).newInstance("str", myManifest, someUrl, aClassLoader);**

Comment: @Hervian I think you have misunderstood the package concept too.

Answer (score 0):

If You mean a deployment package creation, see [izPack](http://izpack.org/) ,
positioned as "A one-stop solution for packaging, distributing and deploying applications. "